# ¿Cómo hacer que un comando detenga su ejecución después de un tiempo determinado?

Tags: bash, script, shell

Cuando usamos `find .` nos trae todo lo hay dentro del directorio actual, pero esto puede demorar si hay demasiados archivos. Lo que quiero saber es como detenerlo después de algunos seg y que continúe con el resto del script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma bien sencilla de implementar un "timeout" por comando es usar justamente la herramienta [`timeout`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) que forma parte de los [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html).

Por ejemplo:

```
timeout 10 find .
```

Lo cual detendrá, o más bien intentará detener al comando `find .` a los 10 segundos. Por defecto se enviará un `SIGTERM` que en algunos casos no alcanza (con `find` sí), en cuyo caso se podría especificar otra señal como ser `timeout -s KILL 10 <comando>` que enviará un `SIGKILL`, o bien `timeout -k 10 5 <comando>` el cual envía un `SIGTERM` a los 10 segundos y si el comando sigue activo a los 5 segundos enviará un `SIGKILL`

Otra forma en caso de no disponer de `timeout`:

```
find . & sleep 10; kill $!
```

En este caso, la única contra es que indefectiblemente el tiempo será el del timeout, si el comando emplea menos tiempo, el `sleep` seguirá corriendo los segundos establecidos.

fuente: [Unix / Linux: Run Command with Timeout](https://stackpointer.io/unix/unix-linux-run-command-with-timeout/500/)

Comment: agradezco su ayuda.@PatricioMoracho